# Trying to write a code in which output should be display text after a delay of 2 seconds using Interval Timer

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
int main()
{
    time_t now;
    struct tm timespace;
    double seconds;
    struct timespec t = { 2 /*seconds*/, 0 /*nanoseconds*/ };
    while (1) {
        time(&now);
        seconds = now;
        printf("%.f Timer Counter\n", seconds);
        timespace = *localtime(&now);
        nanosleep(&t, NULL);
        time(&now);
        seconds = now;
        fflush(stdout);
        printf("%.f Counter Value After two second delay.\n Hellow.\n", seconds);
        seconds = now;
        printf("\n\n\n");
        timespace = *localtime(&now);
        nanosleep(&t, NULL);
        fflush(stdout);

        time(&now);
        seconds = now;
        printf("%.f Counter Value After two second delay.\n Hello World 2.\n", seconds);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Every time I compile this code it says:

```
variable `timespec t' has initializer but incomplete type
```

and

```
'nanosleep' undeclared (first use this function)
```

Comment: nanosleep is linux-only. If you are on Windows you should use Sleep. If you want cross-platform C++, use std::chrono

Comment: @yu_sha – [nanosleep](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/nanosleep.html) is in the POSIX spec, so it's not "linux-only" (though Windows is not a POSIX system). It'll work on BSD and Mac OS X, Unix, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If I wanted a time delay, I will do something like this:

```
int t = time( NULL );
int delay = 2;

while( time(NULL) < (t + delay) );

std::cout << "...";
```

It is fairly close to a two seconds time delay.